# Keirin question on travel Stack Exchange - would it be better here?

Tags: discussion, migration

Over on the travel site we've had [this question about keirin in Japan](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/994/how-to-find-keirin-races-in-japan) that's been there for a while without any answers. It was mentioned that it might be more suitable to the bicycles site here so I thought I'd bring it to your attention.

Should we migrate it here?

#### Update:

migrated: [How to find track/Keirin races when travelling?](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/5691/how-to-find-track-keirin-races-when-travelling)

Comment: See also: http://meta.bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/7/bike-touring-and-camping

Comment: See also: http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/1913/bike-tours-in-athens-greece

Answer (score 4):

I had to [look up what Keirin even is](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keirin) - I don't follow racing - but it's certainly related to cycling. However, we don't have any users in Japan that I'm aware of, though not everyone talks about where they live or puts their location in their profile.

It's not the *best* question, since it's limited to the few weeks the asker will be in Japan, but it's not a bad one either.

Send it over; the worst that can happen is that you get no answers, and you're no worse off.

Comment: I think if it gets migrated here it should be rewritten to a question more like "How do I find Keirin/track racing in an area I'm visiting?"

Comment: I like that. Something that someone else visiting Japan in the future could use to find racing. But let's not make it too general or it'll divorce the question from the real-world problem.

Comment: Hmm there does seem to be too much fuzziness in both directions "too broad" and "too narrow" but in any case in the future consider migrating such questions to travel.SE or at least advising the asker that we also exist. You could also ask meta questions over on our site like this \-:

Comment: @hippietrail - What if we get questions about cycling in [country]? Should we send those over if we're not getting answers?

Comment: @Neil: If they are about travelling by bicycle then certainly send them to travel.SE I would say.

Comment: Stuff like cycle touring is probably more on-topic here, except when it gets away from the actual riding and more about the location and travel, in which case Travel could probably handle the question better than we could.